# Variable cell specification for a csv in R

Tags: r

I wish to use a variable to specify a particular cell in a csv file. I can use:

```
emp1 <- read.csv("C:/Database/data/emp1.csv",as.is=TRUE)
numberofemployee <- 1
> emp1["1", "X.name"]
[1] "ALEX"
```

but if I use:

```
> emp1["numberofemployee", "X.name"]
[1] NA
```

I assume R is looking for numberofemployee as a column header.

How do I get it to see it as an integer so I can specify my cells?

csv file

```
#name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri
ALEX,98,95,73,88,18
BRAD,66,25,72,8,32
JOHN,22,41,78,43,36
```

Comment: A string and a variable name are not the same. `emp1[numberofemployee, "X.name"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you pass strings to the `[]`. This works best when referring to row and columnnames. In case of using `"1"`, R probably makes an educated guess and converts the `"1"` to a `1` (numeric). However, in case of you passing the name of a variable, R cannot do anything else than assume that you are trying to extract something from the `numberofemployee` column. If you want to use the *content* of `numberofemployee`, you need to omit the `"`. R will then interpret that as an R object, whose content you want to use:

```
emp1[numberofemployee, "X.name"]
```